# How to center image with left aligned text overlay

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I would like to have a header image that is centered in the browser window. Within the image I need left aligned text and an icon overlay in upper right corner of image.  All of the elements must flow to get as the window resizes and remain center.  I'm sure it's simple but I just can't seem to make it happen.

```css
#banner{
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}

#bannerText{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:60px;
}

.header_option_overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right:0px;
    left:420px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center_me">
     <div id="banner" >
         <img src="http://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/hotels/Puerto-Vallarta-180016.jpg" width="456" height="190">
         <a href="#home_panel"  class="header_option_overlay"> <img border="0" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/40285808/3/stock-illustration-40285808-hamburger-icon.jpg" width="15" height="15"></a>
         <div id="bannerText">
             <p>Beach's</p>
             <p>Mexico</p>
         </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fatfantasma/twppvmak/)

As you can see the image, text, and icon are all left align to the browser window.  If I try to center everything text and images do not stay together. How do I make everything center in the window?

Comment: Give my answer a try fantasma

Comment: Thanks Dee.  It's not exactly what I wanted but your method/outcome could be useful for me in the future.

Comment: Thank you! Hope whatever you're doing comes out looking good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have resolved, with one of these two examples you can do it, you choose the one that best suits you.

**1-** Setting `display:inline-block` to `#banner` to allows it to fit the width of its content and `text-align: center` to `#center_me` to center the content.

```css
#center_me{
    text-align: center; /*to center the content*/
}
#banner {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;  /*allows it to fit the width of its content*/
}
#bannerText {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:60px;
}
.header_option_overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right: 5px;   /*adjusting to nearly border*/
}
```

```html
<div id="center_me">
    <div id="banner">
        <img src="http://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/hotels/Puerto-Vallarta-180016.jpg" width="456" height="190" /> <a href="#home_panel" class="header_option_overlay"> <img border="0" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/40285808/3/stock-illustration-40285808-hamburger-icon.jpg" width="15" height="15" /></a>

        <div id="bannerText">
            <p>Beach's</p>
            <p>Mexico</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**2-** Setting a fixed width = to the img width to `#banner` and using `margin: 0 auto` to center it.

```css
#banner {
    position:relative;
    width: 456px;  /*setting a fixed width = to the img width*/
    margin: 0 auto;  /*using margin to center it*/
}
#bannerText {
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:60px;
}
.header_option_overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:5px;
    right: 5px;   /*adjusting to nearly border*/
}
```

```html
<div id="center_me">
    <div id="banner">
        <img src="http://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/hotels/Puerto-Vallarta-180016.jpg" width="456" height="190" /> <a href="#home_panel" class="header_option_overlay"> <img border="0" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/40285808/3/stock-illustration-40285808-hamburger-icon.jpg" width="15" height="15" /></a>

        <div id="bannerText">
            <p>Beach's</p>
            <p>Mexico</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Noting that if you have an img bigger than the width that you want, just add `overflow: hidden` to `#banner` to hidden the overflow part of the img and maybe a desired fixed height if you want.

Comment: Your #1 option is exactly what I was looking for.  However, I did have to add    " text-align: left;" in the #bannerText CSS to make it actually work in my case for some reason.  Otherwise the text was centered.  I checked my CSS and nothing was overriding it. Very strange.  Thanks again. :)

Comment: @fatfantasma I'm glad to help you, `text-align` describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. `text-align` does not control the alignment of block elements itself, only their inline content and it is inherited so if you check in the inspect element of chrome or firebug you can see how the `text-align` in `#center_me` is overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you want?

```css
.my-image {
    background-image: url(http://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/hotels/Puerto-Vallarta-180016.jpg);
    width: 456px;
    height: 190px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px 50px;
}
.my-image a img {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-image">
  <p>Beach's</p>
  <p>Mexico</p>
  <a href="#home_panel"><img src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/40285808/3/stock-illustration-40285808-hamburger-icon.jpg" alt=""></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

For HTML:

```
<div id="center_me">
  <div id="banner">
    <img id="back" src="http://images.trvl-media.com/media/content/shared/images/travelguides/hotels/Puerto-Vallarta-180016.jpg">
    <a href="#home_panel" class="header_option_overlay"> <img border="0" src="http://i.istockimg.com/file_thumbview_approve/40285808/3/stock-illustration-40285808-hamburger-icon.jpg" width="15" height="15"></a>
    <div id="bannerText">
      <p>Beach's</p>
      <p>Mexico</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For CSS:

```
#center_me {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#banner {
  position: relative;
}

#banner #back {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
} 

#bannerText {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 40px;
}

.header_option_overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
}
```

hope this helps